# Measuring cpu time for http request in async controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, async-await, cpu-usage

I was reading google SRE book chapter on handling overload : https://sre.google/sre-book/handling-overload/

They mention:

> An interesting part of the puzzle is computing in real time the amount of resources—specifically CPU—consumed by each individual request. This computation is particularly tricky for servers that don't implement a thread-per-request model, where a pool of threads just executes different parts of all requests as they come in, using nonblocking APIs.

I know in a  thread-per-request model, we could simply call getrusage(RUSAGE_THREAD, &r);
but in a ASP.net Controller with async methods it's not guaranteed that code before and after the "await" keyword will execute on the same thread.
and even if it does, it's possible the thread also executed code for other http request.

So is there a way to measure how much cpu time an async function used.

Comment: If you do it right, everything is async and this really can't be measured. CPU really isn't a resource you usually need to worry about in a web server. (My opinion only). I'm curious why you care

Comment: CPU usage on a web server is normally measured _globally_ for the whole process. If in that case you see high usages, let a performance profiler run and check the hot paths, but that's not something you log _all the time_.

Comment: Oliver: for this scenario it need to be dynamically computed so the value can be used by the request load balancer. It cannot simply be computed offline with a profiler.

Comment: if you read this chapter from the google SRE book it will be more clear. But the goal is to know if the request is spending 80% of its time simply waiting for a response from (database/disk) or if its spending 80% of its time on the cpu crunching numbers.

Comment: Can't you use `BenchmarkDotnet` for this?

Comment: klekmek: BenchmarkDotnet  measure wall clock time! not CPU time.

Answer (score 0):

Managed memory allocations will cause GC work that is done in other threads. Caches are managed in other threads.

Measuring whatever in direct dependency of a request is misleading.

If you have performance issues, you should collect metrics, ETW traces, memory dumps and analyze them.

Comment: This is *not* for offline performance analysis. But to use in a load balancing algorithm.

Comment: That is the wrong metric for that. You can load balance based on the overall load o the server instead. You can even load balance when there's a blocking GC executing.

Comment: Paulo Morgado: this is what google are doing,  and it seem to work very well for them ;0) This is in case of multi-tenant, you need to start throttling tenant that use more than their quota

Comment: Does the tenant have any control on how much CPU their requests use?

Comment: Paulo: you can think of an endpoint with 2 type of request « A » cheap one and « B » expensive one. Each user decide how many request they send (rps) and of which type. If there the server is currently receiving request from 2 user it need to give each a fair share of the server capacity.

Comment: RPS is a metric the client can control. It's up to the server the provide the resources and good use of the resources. I wound not subscribe to a service where I'm billed or throttled by CPU usage without reviewing the code myself.

Comment: in system that work like this. one http response header contain the « cost » of the request so it’s easy to test how much you are using it’s not random.

Answer (score 0):

Found one Nuget this provides this feature.

https://github.com/devizer/Universe.CpuUsage

Using the class CpuUsageAsyncWatcher

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    // Here is a "middleware" that displays total CPU usage
    // of all the Tasks executed by ASP.NET Core pipeline during each http request
    app.Use(async (context, next) =>
    {
        CpuUsageAsyncWatcher watcher = new CpuUsageAsyncWatcher();
        await next.Invoke();
        watcher.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine($"Cpu Usage by http request is {watcher.GetSummaryCpuUsage()}");
    });
}
```